# WCF DataContract DataMember as simpleType in XSD?

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, datacontractserializer

Using WCF and DataContract serializer, how can I represent a data member to reflect as a simpleType when viewing the XSD. For example:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://mydomain.xyz/example")]
public class MyType
{
 [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
 public SomeBasicDataType basicAttribute { get; set; }

 [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
 public SomeComplexType complexElement { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I want someBasicDataType to be `<xs:simpleType name="SomeBasicDataType ">` in the the accompanying XSD instead of `<xs:complexType name="SomeBasicDataType">`

Comment: I believe you cannot do it with a DataContract. Possibly xml serializer could work.

Answer (score 0):

XSD does not allow simple types to contain either elements or attributes defined elsewhere in the schema.

Simple types are created by deriving them from existing simple types (built-in data types and other derived simple types)

Simple types are usually [derived by restriction](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_restriction.asp), but can also be derived by list or union.